Can Balaguer’s argument we don’t, and couldn’t, have any good argument for Platonism or ficitonalism in math extend to realism/antirealism in general?
Mark Balaguer is a philosopher who advances the position there is one form of mathematical Platonism, that every consistent mathematical object exists, and one form of anti Platonism, ficitonalism. Also that there is no fact of the matter about which is correct/true.
Platonism is usually identified as realism regarding mathematical objects, although there might be other forms of realism in math. Fictionalism is usually one of many anti-realist positions about mathematical objects.
I’m wondering if we can use much of Balaguer’s argument about that status of mathematical objects to have the same conclusion of realism and anti realism about all kinds of objects. Namely, that there is no fact of the matter toward realism vs anti realism writ large.
I don’t feel like I can give a comprehensive and/or succinct reason why or why not, so I come here for your wisdom.

Not directly. Balaguer's argument is an inference to the best explanation rooted in the Benacerraf's dilemma: if mathematical truths are platonic we cannot know them since platonic entities are causally inert; if mathematical truths are not platonic then they lack objects to be truths about. Balaguer's "full-blooded platonism" resolves the problem of access, we do not need causal interaction to know if everything (consistent) platonically exists. But there is no such problem for non-platonic entities.

@Conifold if there is a (realist) position that only universals (or tropes?) exist (and they’d have to be abstract), and an anti realist position where we lack objects for there to be truths about (a pessimistic view of science/anti realism in science perhaps) then could we do it directly?

Balaguer's point is, basically, that for objects we can only know without interaction there is no way (for us) to distinguish between platonism and fictionalism. But this is the case for platonic objects not just because they are abstract, but also because they are non-contingent, that is what allows knowledge of them 'sight unseen', 'by reason alone'. Even if one could somehow reduce the concrete world to universals, I do not see how they would account for perception and contingent knowledge on his model. To argue that realism/anti-realism are indistinguishable, one has to address those.

@Conifold the contingency of non-mathematical abstract universals does put the kibosh on this idea then, thank you. At least I’m not prepared to take it further

I see no issue in extending Herr Balaguer's argument beyond mathematics, to other/the whole ontological domain(s). His condition for existence is clear-cut: For x to exist, it has to be consistent (x itself can't be a contradiction and x shouldn't entail a contradiction).
If we equate consistent with possible, we have modal/ontological explosion (something just has to be possible to actually exist) and isn't the definition of impossible predicated on contradiction?

This is a pretty good argument. I don’t think it fully overcomes the perception and contingency of physical objects Conifold brought up but it’s interesting in its own right. There are perceptual doubters like Donald Hoffman who may  take them for indistinguishable.

@JKusin, what about MUH (Mathematical Universe Hypothesis)?

Tegmark does believe we have current reason to be strong perceptual doubters about things like the flow of time. So that’s a plus. But, he predicts huge progress in psychology which will eliminate these errors in perception. So down the road we would be total realists with no room for fictions. I think we need something where fictions remain powerful. Or for your route, where modalities explode. Which I don’t think would under the MUH. MUH is all real and static.

My version of a Balaguer extension, built on the equivalence between consistency and possibility leads to ontological explosion. Fiction becomes meaningless(?), because everything except stuff that entail a contradiction would exist. I wonder how we could tweak Balaguer to make even Schrodinger's cat exist. @JKusin

What about Alexius Meinong's jungle? My personal interpretation of Meinong's idea is that even nothing exists in some sense. @JKusin

I think that's closer but remember we need a fictionalist account to remain coequal.

@JKusin, if you have other objectives, sure!
